# Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04.4 + Windows 10 on laptop with SSD + HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd, hybrid

I have a laptop with 512GB SSD + 1TB HDD on which I'd like to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 that came preinstalled. A tech support person who helped me setup the laptop after I bought it, partitioned my SSD into two - backing up my Windows System Image on the other empty partition `D:`. So I'm confused about where I should install Ubuntu.

I'm completely new to handling OSes, so most of the technical details about partitioning and mounting goes over my head. I plan to use Ubuntu for programming and Windows for simple personal usage such as storing files, web browsing, light coding, etc. I'd like to have good performance on both of them.

*Optionally,* I'd like to access my files on the HDD from both Ubuntu and Windows. Please advise me on how I should go about partitioning my disks safely and install Ubuntu. I'd deeply appreciate if someone could ELI5.

Here is an image of the current [disk partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5FgF.png). My laptop has 512GB M.2 SSD, 2.5" SATA 1TB HDD, with 8GB RAM installed at the moment. It uses UEFI.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). There is also a guided "Install alongside Windows" option. In order to get that option, two conditions must be met. 1) you need enough **unpartitioned free space** for Ubuntu (minimum is 25GB). 2) You have to boot the Ubuntu installation USB consistent with your Windows install (typically UEFI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey definitely you can do this !

> First and foremost you must have both Oses on same disk ! In your case it
> should be on either Disk0 or Disk1.

But You should install ubuntu on Disk0 as Windows it already installed on Disk0.

Please Follow this steps :-

1. Make partition of 30-50 GB in Disk0 (or you can use that New Volume D)
2. Take backup of that Volume D and Delete this partition and make is unallocated.
3. Now Make a bootable pendrive and install ubuntu in this unallocated partition.
4. At the point of selection of boot partition(during ubuntu installation) you will have to select this SSD (Disk0) In order to make your pc dual boot.
5. And with this you will be able to access  1TB HDD from ubuntu and windows as well !
6. see this answer for dual boot instructions : [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359467/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows/1359825#1359825)

I hope it will help you !!

Comment: Thanks! One question, do I not have to do anything else to the HDD in order to access it from both operating systems?

Comment: No, it will be accessed by both the OSes!